# Using Lagrange multipliers to find the a point on a Paraboloid surface that is closet to the origin.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

How can you find the point which has the shortest distance to the origin? I have an paraboloid surface $z=1-x^2-y^2$ where $z \geq -1$. so the surface is bounded by the $z=1-x^2-y^2$ and $z \geq -1$
I need to use Lagrange multipliers to solve this. 
I have set up the $z=1-x^2-y^2$ as my constraints, but I do not know what to do with the $z \geq-1$.

Comment: I cant seem to use \geqq or any of the \ge type way to indicate the inequalities

Comment: Hi Gary, if you want to use \ge, you'll have to wrap your LaTeX code in dollar signs: `$z \ge -1$`

Comment: fixed i was a little confused reading the MathJax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variables are $x$, $y$ and $z$ .

The objective function is minimizing the distance to the origin $f(x,y,z)=x^2 +y^2+z^2$.

The constraints are $g(x,y,z)=-1-z \leq 0$ and $h(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z-1=0$.

If you use KKT conditions, it will be easy to solve the problem.

Comment: so would i do the constraint twice? cuz trying to use Lagrange multipler got me stuck at 2x=-2x$\Lambda$ ,2y=-2y$\Lambda$, and 2z=-$\Lambda$

Comment: @Gary, I have edited my answer, It should be clear now. You have 2 constraints.